# How can I set ComponentRegistration after RegistrationSource in autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

sample code:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterSource(new RegistrationSource());
builder.RegisterType<Cmd1>().AsSelf().As<ICmd>();
IContainer container = builder.Build();
var cmds = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<ICmd>>();
```

RegistrationSource will provide `Cmd2` type, and the `cmds` result is `cmd1`, `cmd2`. But I want `Cmd2`, `Cmd1`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Supplementary：I want to get an instance from RegistrationSource,if the RegistrationSource can't resove an component,it will return a default component that providered by RegisterType or other solution

Comment: could you edit your question and include your clarification ?

Answer (score 0):

> if the RegistrationSource can't resove an component,it will return a default component that providered by RegisterType or other solution

`RegistrationSource` doesn't return anything. It only register new registration to the component registry.

I think what you want is that when *Autofac* resolve something, it will first try to use a registration provided by a `RegistrationSource` and if there is not any, it should try to use a registration provided without `RegistrationSource`. Is that right ?

This is not possible. All registrations are equivalent whether the are provided by a `RegistrationSource` or not.

But instead of registering many `IFoo` you can register many named `IFoo`and only one `IFoo` that will choose the correct named `IFoo` to use.

```
builder.Register(c => c.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<Meta<IFoo>>>("Ordered")
                       .OrderBy(metaFoo => (Int32)metaFoo.Metadata["order"])
                       .Select(metaFoo => metaFoo.Value)
                       .First())
       .As<IFoo>();

// classic registration
builder.RegisterType<Foo1>()
       .Named<IFoo>("Ordered")
       .WithMetadata("order", 20);


// this registration can be provided by a RegistrationSource
builder.RegisterType<Foo2>()
       .Named<IFoo>("Ordered")
       .WithMetadata("order", 10);
```

Now *Autofac* will check the `order` metadata named `IFoo` registrations when it resolves `IFoo`

---

**the following answer was made before the clarification**

You can use the `PreserveExistingDefaults` method that will push the registration to the end of the list of registration.

```
builder.RegisterType<Foo1>().As<IFoo>();
builder.RegisterType<Foo2>().As<IFoo>().PreserveExistingDefaults();

// ...

container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IFoo>>() => Foo1, Foo2
```

In your case, if you want to control the order of registrations, I would recommend doing something with meta.

```
builder.RegisterType<Foo1>().As<IFoo>().WithMetadata("order", 10);
builder.RegisterType<Foo2>().As<IFoo>().WithMetadata("order", 20);
builder.RegisterType<Foo3>().As<IFoo>().WithMetadata("order", 15);
// ...

IEnumerable<IFoo> foos = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<Meta<IFoo>>>()
                                    .OrderBy(o => (Int32)o.Metadata["order"])
                                    .Select(o => o.Value);

// foos => Foo1, Foo3, Foo2
```

If you want to go further, you can implement a custom `IRegistrationSource` that will provide registration for `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`. Each time you will want an ordered enumerable, you will be able to resolve `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` and order will be guaranteed.

Comment: I mean I have a RegistrationSource dynamic generation,and I want the RegistrationSource at first, if I resove ICmd , I can got cmd2, if RegistrationSource have no icmd , it will retrun cmd1 , this is my purpose 。

Comment: @kbuddy Sorry, I don't have it. You no longer work with `IEnumerable<T>` ? Could you edit your question and explain what you are trying to do with your `IRegistrationSource` ? The code of your `IRegistrationSource` may help better understand your requirement.

Comment: Supplementary：I want to get an instance from RegistrationSource,if the RegistrationSource can't resove an component,it will return a default component that providered by RegisterType or other solution